# Has there ever been a duel, where Yugi used every existing card right?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Has there ever been a duel, where Yugi (or Yami) wasn't protected by the plot armour and won a duel with cards that were released during that time and used the effect as stated on the actual card *in real life*?
Anime and Manga are very welcome as source.
And for the love of god: Can somebody please explain what "Pot of Greed" does?!?

Comment: Does the in-series card's effect have to match its effect in real life? Some cards in the anime were different from their real-life counterparts but still had consistent effects throughout the series (like Card of Sanctity).

Comment: Yep, I was thinking abour real life effects.

Comment: I can't answer the first part of your question since I haven't seen the anime since duelist kingdom but based on that I doubt that that has ever happened. Pot of Greed (IRL) allows the users to draw 2 cards from their deck, unfortunately this card has been banned from playing for quite some time now.

Comment: the original manga and anime precede the card game release by a few years, so they did a lot of balancing when making the actual card game. You'd be hard pressed to find cards that were actually kept intact after the transition aside from very select cards, so even if there were some cards that were used as intended later on in the TCG (Monster Reborn, Polimerization), you can be sure that there was no duel in which all the cards used were completely faithful to their later TCG counterparts, there was at the very least 1 BS card in every single duel. Especially during the Duelist Kingdom arc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly can't recall any where he didn't have an 'additional' affect to something, or went and did something impossible for a card game (like smashing the moon against mako or breaking the float ring against the floating castle)...
Also pot of greed lets you draw 2 cards from your deck